# Equivalent inner product on Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, (\cdot,\cdot)_1)$ be a Hilbert space. Suppose also that $(\cdot,\cdot)_2$ is an inner product on $H$ which is norm-equivalent with $(\cdot,\cdot)$.

Is it possible to write the second inner product in terms of the first?

For example, perhaps it is true that
$$(a,b)_2 = (Ta,b)_1$$
for some operator $T$? If so what is known about $T$?

Comment: Define an operator $T$ on $H$ exactly like you did: $(Ta, b)_1 = (a,b)_2$. By norm equivalence of the inner products and Riesz representation, $T$ is a well-defined bounded operator. In fact, $T$ is an invertible positive operator. One could say the space $(H, (\cdot,\cdot)_1)$ is "renormed" by $T$.

Comment: @Michael You should post that as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Define an operator $T$ on $H$ exactly like you did: $(Ta,b)_1=(a,b)_2$. By norm equivalence of the inner products and Riesz representation, $T$ is a well-defined bounded operator. In fact, $T$ is an invertible positive operator. One could say the space $(H,(⋅,⋅)_1)$ is "renormed" by $T$.